# Where can I ask a question about Notepad++?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I needed to ask if it is possible to copy rich text from Notepad++, and I realized that it's probably off-topic in most of the community I already know.

Is there a generic software community for asking this things?

Comment: This kind of question would, in my eyes, be best answered by **trying**.

Comment: You can use [tag:notepad++] tag for your question. There are already 2000+ questions

Comment: @Satpal you might wanna put this as an answer.

Comment: If it's not a programming question, there is the [notepad++](http://superuser.com/tags/notepad%2b%2b/info) tag on [SU] as well.

Comment: I've added a bounty here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509340/pasting-into-notepad-and-preserving-colours-styles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarize the comments (thanks Satpal and S.L. Barth):

- If it's a programming question (regex, macro...): [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/notepad%2B%2B/info)
- If it's **not** a programming question (installation, interface...): [Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/notepad%2B%2B/info)

Comment: Would you be willing to elaborate on this answer? There seems to be a lot of overlap between programming and-non programming question about Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

On SO, You can use [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) tag for your question. There are already 2000+ questions.

Comment: So it's possible to open questions on SO which are not strictly inherent to development? I like this a lot do you think this question is worth to be asked here on meta?

Comment: @Sam, based on few question short answer is Yes. As I am not active on [tag:notepad++] so not 100% sure about it

Comment: @sam, questions about development tools are ok.